# JAVA_HOME environment variable semicolon issue for maven

Tags: java, windows, maven, environment-variables

I have two versions of java installed, hence my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable looks something like this:
`C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_281;C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-11.0.10`

Now the issue is, when I run the command `mvn -v` in cmd, it gives me the error:
**NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE.**

I figured out what was causing this. The semi-colon differentiating two different Java installations. So, for the mvn commands to work, what I do is keep only one java installation path in `JAVA_HOME` variable . So currently I am limited to using only one Java installation due to this.

Is there a way around this, where I can use both Java installations for different projects and still be able to use mvn commands?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I have two versions of java installed, hence my JAVA_HOME environment variable looks something like this: `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_281;C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-11.0.10`

That is your problem: trying to shoe-horn two versions of Java into `JAVA_HOME`.

Your `JAVA_HOME` should never look like that. The `JAVA_HOME` should refer to exactly one Java installation.  It is not "search path", and if you try to configure it as one, Maven won't work.   Maven will treat the separator as part of the installation pathname and fail.

> Is there a way around this, where I can use both Java installations for different projects and still be able to use mvn commands?

1. Set / change the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in the current shell env by hand or using a shell alias whenever you switch between projects.
2. Write some clever wrapper scripts (e.g. for the `mvn` command) that use a different `JAVA_HOME` settings depending on what the current directory is.

NB: Either of those solutions can be applied irrespective of the operating system you are using for development work.  (Including Windows!)  And there are likely to be other solutions too.

Comment: Thank you. Your points 1 and 2 seem to be geared towards a Linux environment, I use windows. Do you have any work around for that?

Comment: 1) You can set an environment variable in a Windows CMD shell by hand.  2) You should be able to write a clever Windows batch file though I can't help you.  (The batch file language is horrible, IMO, and I really don't what to go there again.) 3) You could install and use Cygwin or WSL.  Workaround 1) will definitely work.